# Numpy array indexing with a List: difference between arr[:][li] and arr[:,li]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

What is the explanation of the following behavior:

```
import numpy as np    
arr = np.zeros((3, 3))
li = [1,2]
print('output1:', arr[:, li].shape)
print('output2:', arr[:][li].shape)

>>output1: (3, 2)
>>output2: (2, 3)
```

I would expect output2 to be equal to output1.

Comment: a[:] only copies the a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a different array where it's easier to see the difference:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
>>> arr
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

The first case `arr[:, li]` will select all elements from the first dimension (in this case all the rows), then index the array with `[1, 2]`, which means just leaving out the first column:

```py
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 8]])
```

Hence, the shape of this is (3, 2).

The other case `arr[:]` will copy the original array, so it doesn't change the shape, therefore it's equvivalent to `arr[li]`, hence the output shape is `(2, 3)`. In general you should avoid double indexing an array, because that might create views twice, which is inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the the correct output.

In first line

```
print('output1:', arr[:, li].shape)
```

You are printing `2nd` and `3rd` element of each subarray within `arr`, thus getting `3` elements each containing `2` values.

In second line

```
print('output2:', arr[:][li].shape)
```

You are selecting first the whole array, then from the whole array you select `2nd` and `3rd` element (each containing `3` elements themselves), thus getting `2` elements each containing `3` values.

Answer (score 1):

The difference can be seen if you examine this code -

```
import numpy as np    
arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
li = [1,2]
print('output1:', arr[:, li])
print('output2:', arr[:][li])
```

This gives -

```
[[1 2]
 [4 5]
 [7 8]]
```

and

```
[[3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
```

When you do `arr[:, [1, 2]]`, what you are saying that you want to take all the rows of the array (`:` specifies this) and, from that, take column `[1, 2]`.

On the other hand, when you do `arr[:]`, you are referring to the full array first. Out of which you are again taking the first two rows.

Essentially, in the second case, `[1 2]` is referring to the row axis of the original array while in the first case, it's referring to the column.